# Should opinion based questions be asked?

Tags: discussion

This Question:

[What are the parts and the general framework of OpenCog?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2381/what-are-the-parts-and-the-general-framework-of-opencog)

Asks for an opinion and a recommendation,that is to say;what the general ideas behind open cog are and whether you would endorse it as a insightful take on AGI

Do you think such question should be asked?

Answer (score 5):

## No, no, no.

We have a *close reason* for opinion-based questions. They are explicitly off-topic on Stack Exchange sites.

When you click on 'Close'<sup>1</sup> (you gain close vote privileges at 500 rep on public Beta sites, 3,000 on graduated sites (1 rep during private beta)), you see something like this:

[image: vtc]

See that 'primarily opinion-based' down there? That's one of the close reasons. (That blue '1' means that someone has already voted to close it for that reason. It takes 5 votes to close it.)

---

<sup>1</sup>If you don't yet have closing privileges, you can *flag* it as needing to be closed. Click on 'flag', then click on 'should be closed because...' and you'll see something like this:

[image: ftc]

See '[What should I not ask about here?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)' in the Help Center.